# MVVM: Using custom fonts with XAML in UWP

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp

I'm trying to use icon font from [weather-icons](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/) in an UWP application.

In my XAML I have something like

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <FontFamily x:Key="WeatherFonts">/Assets/Fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf#Weather Icons</FontFamily>
</Grid.Resources>
<TextBlock x:Name="tbFontAwesome" 
               Text="{Binding CurrentWeather.Icon}" 
               FontFamily="{StaticResource WeatherFonts}" 
               Foreground="White" 
               FontSize="72"/>
```

In my *ViewModel* I'm setting the

```
CurrentWeather.Icon = "&#xf00d;"
```

If I just hardcode this in the XAML, it works fine.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbFontAwesome" 
               Text="&#xf00d;" 
               FontFamily="{StaticResource WeatherFonts}" 
               Foreground="White" 
               FontSize="72"/>
```

When I use the hardcoded XAML, the icon shows up just fine, but if I try doing the binding to the string, the `TextBlock` just shows the string and not the icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xf00d;")`.

Comment: This worked. I was having trouble with it, but it turns out that there was another issue as well. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible nws. Glad to hear you worked it out!